# \usepackage{graphicx} --> compiling does not work anymore

Tags: latex, pdflatex

As soon as I use \usepackage{graphicx} in the preamble, the compiling does not work anymore. The strange thing is that I do not get a warning or an error, it just does not compile (regardless whether I use pdflatex, latex or quick build). I am using Windows 10, MikTex and Texmaker.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
I would like to add a figure. 
\end{document}
```

When I click on PDFLaTeX and afterwards on View Pdf, nothing happens (no warning, no error, just the blank white sheet). As soon as I delete \usepackage{graphicx} , it works perfectly. Any idea? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not likely to help future visitors (and reproduction is not possible with an up-to-date system).

Answer (score 0):

My only thought is that you may have an outdated pdfTeX version: you probably need to upgrade your MikTeX installation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I had the most recent version but apparently sth at the installation of MiKTex went wrong. I re-installed MiKTeX, now it works perfectly.